# instance of Class<T[]> in java in order to use in json parser

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am using the json google library. we can have this:

```
Public Class JsonParsing<T> {   

     private Gson gson;

     public JsonParsing(GsonBuilder builder) {
         this.gson = builder.create();
     }

     public T[] fromJsonFromArray(String json, Class<T[]> classOfT) {
         return gson.fromJson(json, classOfT);
     }
}
```

How we can create the instance of `Class<T[]>` in order to pass to this method?

Addenda:

I tried to create a generic method :

```
    public <T> T[] fromJsonFromArray(String json) {
        final Type type = new TypeToken<T[]>(){}.getType();
        return gson.fromJson(json, classOfT);
    }
```

It seems that I can not have a `T[]` as return. Then how can I parse an array of data with json format? 
Note: It is possible to do it in a non-generic way. 
Couldn't we have any generic solution?

Answer (score 2):

You could change your method to:

```
public T fromJsonFromArray(String json, Class<T> classOfT) {
    return gson.fromJson(json, classOfT);
}
```

and call it like (for example):

```
fromJsonFromArray(someString, new Byte[0].getClass());
```

---

Note: it strikes me that this should probably be a generic method like so:

```
public <T> T fromJsonFromArray(String json, Class<T> classOfT) {
    return gson.fromJson(json, classOfT);
}
```

If you rely on the type parameter from the enclosing type (which your first example does), I don't see the purpose of taking a `classOfT` argument.

Comment: I have added an addenda to my question. Can you check it out? `T` as resturn type seems to work, but what about T[]?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [TokenType](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.1.1/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html).

Something like?

```
Type yourType = new TypeToken<YourClass[]>() {}.getType();
```

Comment: Good point. I have used Type, but still couldn´t implement that generic solution that I am looking for.