# How refactor my code with java generics and google Gson

Tags: java, android, json, generics, optimization

Hello i have this (ugly) code:

```
public static <T> List<T> convertaParaListaCidades(String JSONObject) {
        List<Cidade> lista = new ArrayList<Cidade>();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<Cidade>>() {}.getType();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        try {
            Log.i("INFO", "Tentando converter o json.");
            lista = gson.fromJson(JSONObject, type);
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Erro " + e.toString()
                    + " ao converter o json, resultado: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Erro " + e.toString()
                    + " ao converter o json, resultado: " + e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Erro " + e.toString()
                    + " ao converter o json, resultado: " + e.toString());
        }
        return (List<T>) lista;
    }
```

and this:

```
public static <T> List<T> convertaParaListaBairros(String JSONObject) {
        List<Bairro> lista = new ArrayList<Bairro>();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<Bairro>>() {}.getType();
        ...
    }
```

and this:

```
public static <T> List<T> convertaParaListaDeBusca(String JSONObject) {
        List<ElementosPesquisados> lista = new ArrayList<ElementosPesquisados>();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<ElementosPesquisados>>() {}.getType();
        ...
    }
```

**So what is your problem?**
I need deserialize json to object, and at present i have 4 methods ( that do the same ) only changing the object to deserialize the json.

**Why you don't use generics?**
Yes, i tried to it, but... Gson() deserialize the json very well but isn't a type of object that i want *Estado,Cidade or Bairro* is always *LinkedTreeMap*, and my code don't recognizes this type.

The question? How could i compact this code for he be more reliable and maintainable ( 4 methods for do the same isn't a good thing ).

obs: if i call 
`Util.<Cidade> convertaParaListaCidades(json);` it always return *LinkedTreeMap*.

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360637/instance-of-classt-in-java-in-order-to-use-in-json-parser, could be useful for you.

Comment: @Ali i used it instead List<Cidade> lista = new ArrayList<Cidade>();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<Cidade>>() {}.getType();
i used List<T> lista = new ArrayList<T>();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<T>>() {}.getType();
when i use the generic strategy, i alwyas receive LinkedTreeMap. What 
i could do with this map? ( use a foreach to cast every element inside him? )